# Sort second column using linux command

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Is it possible to sort text horizontally?
For e.g. I have this hunspell file that has all the English words followed by tags. (It may contain unicode text and millions of words)

```
test/BACac
this/QPR
line/MNP
again/Xx
```

I need to sort tags (preferably: small letters first and then capital)
Expected:

```
test/acABC
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/xX
```

I can do this in pandas. But I will like to know if I can complete the task using only linux commands!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='/', header=None)
df.columns = ['word', 'tags']
df['tags']=df['tags'].map(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([i for i in x])))
df['final'] = df['word'] + '/' + df['tags'] 
df['final'].to_csv('result.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for "sorted_in" and splitting a string into chars when a null separator is specified:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="/"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}
{
    split($2,lets,"")
    $2 = ""
    for (i in lets) {
        $2 = $2 lets[i]
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
test/ABCac
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/Xx
```

To get output where lower case letters sort before upper case you'd have to find a locale with such a collation order and set `LC_ALL=<that locale>` before running the script or convert all upper case to lower case and vice versa first, then do the sort, then convert them back before printing or do something similar by putting a decorator char in front of each real char such as all lower case letters get a leading `A` while upper get a leading `a` to again force a different order, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="/"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}
{
    split($2,lets,"")

    for (i in lets) {
        lets[i] = ( lets[i] ~ /[[:lower:]]/ ? "A" : "a" ) lets[i]
    }

    $2 = ""
    for (i in lets) {
        $2 = $2 substr(lets[i],2)
    }    
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
test/acABC
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/xX
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit awkward in awk.  But sometimes the best awk really is perl:

```
perl -F/ -lane 'printf "%s/%s\n", $F[0], join "", sort split //, $F[1];'
```

or

```
perl -F/ -lape '$_ = $F[0] . "/". join "", sort split //, $F[1];'
```

or

```
perl -lape 's@(?=/)(.*)@join "", sort split //, $1@e'
```

All of the above use the same principle, but the final solution deserves some explanation.  The `(?=/)` is a negative look ahead assertion, so that the expression `(?=/)(.*)` matches all text after the first `/` in the line, but does not consume the `/`.  All of the characters after the `/` are placed into the first matching group, so that the `sort split` can operate on them.  The `split //, $1`, splits the match group into individual characters which are passed to `sort`, and then rejoined with no divider by join.  The result of the `join/sort/split` is used as the replacement for the matched pattern.

Comment: @Sundeep There are a couple of tricks you can use to sort lower case first.  Ideally, you would create a LOCALE that sorts that way, but `perl` allows you to specify the sort criteria explicitly.  In this case, though, it's probably easier to use a hack: convert all uppercase to lowercase, sort, and the switch back.  eg `perl -lape 'y/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/; s@(?=/)(.*)@join "", sort split //, $1@e; y/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sed -E 's#/([[:upper:]]*)(.*)#/\2\1#' file | sort -ft/ -k2,2
```

Swap the lower and uppercase letters in the second field then sort the result on the second field regardless of case.

If the upper and lowercase letters are entwined, use:

```
sed -E ':a;s#/([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)#/\1\3\2#;ta' file |
sort -ft/ -k2,2
```

---

I misunderstood the question:

```
sed -E ':a;s#/([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)#/\1\3\2#;ta' file |
sed -zE 's#/([[:lower:]]*)(.*)#/\n\1\n\2#mg' |
sed '2~3,+1s/.*/echo "&" | sed -z "s#\\B#\\n#g" | sort | sed -z "s#\\n##g"/e' |
sed 'N;N;s/\n//g'
```

Untangle the lower from the uppercase letters following the `/` and place the lowercase letters first.

Separate the each line into a 3 line record, the first line being the first field the second and third lines being the lower and uppercase letters from the second field respectively.

Sort every second and third line by breaking out each line into a single line for each letter of that line. Then sort the resulting set of lines and reconstitute the set of lines within lines back to a single line.

An alternative, perhaps better?:

```
sed -zE 's/(.*\/)(.*)/\1\n\2/mg' file |
sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/echo "\2"|sed -z "s#\\B#\\n#g"|sort|sed -z "s#\\n##g"|sed "s#^#\1#"/e' |
sed -E ':a;s/\/([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)/\/\1\3\2/;ta'
```

Of course, there a utilities to do some of these:

```
sed -zE 's/(.*\/)(.*)/\1\n\2/mg' file |
sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/echo "\2"|fold -b1|sort|tr -d "\\n"|sed "s#^#\1#"/e' |
sed -E ':a;s/\/([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)/\/\1\3\2/;ta
```

In fact the solution may be presented on one line as one substitution:

```
 sed -E 's/^(.*\/)(.*)/echo "\2"|fold -b1|sort|tr -d "\\n"|sed -E ":a;s#^([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)#\\1\\3\\2#;ta;s#^#\1#"/e' file
```

Comment: `sort -k2,2` is the first instinct, but the OP doesn't want to sort lines.  The lines stay in the same place, while the string in the 2nd column of each line is being modified.

Comment: Oops! Offered another solution see above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate solution with `perl` which gives lowercase first:

```sh
$ perl -F'/' -lane '$s = join "", sort split //, $F[1];
                    print $F[0], "/", $s =~ s/^([A-Z]++)(.+)/$2$1/r' ip.txt
test/acABC
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/xX
```

Another alternative:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's|.*/\K.+|join("", sort split //, $&) =~ s/^([A-Z]++)(.+)/$2$1/r|e' ip.txt
test/acABC
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/xX
```

Answer (score 2):

Another GNU sed alternative:

*parse.sed*

```
# Save line to hold-space
h

# Remove word
s:.*/::

# New-line separate letters
s/./&\n/g
s/\n$//

# Quote new-line separated string
s/^|$/'/g

# Sort the letters and remove new-lines
s/^/echo /
s/$/ | sort/e
s/\n//g

# Move capital letters to the end (thanks @potong)
:a
s/([[:lower:]]*)([[:upper:]]+)([[:lower:]]+)/\1\3\2/
ta

# Recombine word and tag
G
s:/.*::
s:([^\n]*)\n(.*):\2/\1:
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Ef parse.sed infile
```

Output:

```
test/acABC
this/PQR
line/MNP
again/xX
```